# store website invite token parameter during FB login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, token, omniauth

A user can share our website url with his invite token as `www.weburl.com/invite_token`. Then a user can signup using his FB account. After logging in am loosing the invite token because of FB login.

How do `I propagate or save this invite_token` during `auth/facebook/callback` to my login page.

Gems used in my app are:

```
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'koala'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried HTML5 LocalStorage. 
So here a quick solution:

User supplied `www.weburl.com/123123123` to another user. Then Second user clicks on the link and lands on your homepage. Now you need to save the token in the HTML5 Storage.

Something like this:

```
window.localStorage.setItem("invite_token", '123123123');
```

Now Your user will use the Facebook account to login. After user logged in, and landed in the Dashboard or UserLanding Page ( I assume ) you simply call the

```
 var foo = window.localStorage.getItem("invite_token");
   // Now Save foo with Ajax or something like that
```

Save it, then remove it:

```
 window.localStorage.removeItem("invite_token");
```

Done!

Answer (score 0):

You can store the invite_token as either [cookies](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Cookies.html) or [session data](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#what-are-sessions-questionmark) in your app and then retrieve them.